# Unable to bind model in ajax.beginform() or ajax.actionLink() postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, aspnet-compiler

when I am posting the form back using Ajax.ActionLink() I am getting null values for all the properties. I have also tried the same using @ajax.beginform(). But i ended up with an error "Unexpected token u" in the console. Please help.

My class goes like this

```
public class Search
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public int ContinentId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

My View goes like this

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.BusinessLogic.Search
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var continetList = (SelectList)ViewBag.TargetContinentName;
var infoTypesList = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Infotype;
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText)<br/>
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions{    HttpMethod = "POST",    UpdateTargetId = "submitId",  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
LoadingElementId = "loadingId"})
</div>
```

My controller goes like this

```
//POST:/Home/
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Search(Search search, int? page)
    {
        //Code goes here
        //Here the object search is giving me null values for all the properties
        return PartialView("_Search",listInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **Ajax.BeginForm** like this:

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.BusinessLogic.Search
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var continetList = (SelectList)ViewBag.TargetContinentName;
var infoTypesList = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Infotype;
}

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", 
 new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "submitId",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "loadingId"
}, 
new  { page = 1}))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ContinentId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.City)

<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search"/>
}
```

Comment: for @ajax.beginform() the error is- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Comment: And for @ajax.actionLink- I am getting a null value in the Search controller

Comment: using ajaxlink you can't post its only get request and i tested on m,y system its not throwing any error you are doing some other thing wrong i suspect

Comment: its showing me some error exactly here- jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) {
 return JSON.parse( data + "" );
};

Comment: Its not working. The button is posting the form back to the server

Comment: you have to include jquery unobtrusive ajax file to work ajax post

Comment: added that. I am seeing null values in the controller.

Comment: No ajax form is showing root. I am getting the null values in ajax.actionlink

Comment: you have to use AjaxForm not actionlink